# Extract string from a Tuple in python with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, tuples, psycopg2

I have written a web.py service in python to access PostGres and get the table names inside the specific database.

**CODE:**

```
 def GET(self,r):
          web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',      '*')
          web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
          tables = []
          datasetID = web.input().dataSetID
          cursor = conn.cursor()
          cursor.execute("select relname from pg_class where relkind='r' and relname !~ '^(pg_|sql_)';")
          tablesWithDetails =    cursor.fetchall()
          print tablesWithDetails
          for x in tablesWithDetails:
            x.replace("(", "")
            x.replace(")","")
            tables.append(x)
            print tables;
```

This prints the table as follows,

```
[('acam_datasegregationdetails',), ('acam_datasegregationheader',), ('idn_accessinformation',), ('idn_b2cuseraccountmapping',), ('idn_b2cuserdevicemapping',), ('idn_b2cusers',), ('idn_roles',), ('idn_useraccountmapping')]
```

**Needed Output:**

```
['acam_datasegregationdetails', 'acam_datasegregationheader', idn_accessinformation', 'idn_b2cuseraccountmapping', 'idn_b2cuserdevicemapping', 'idn_b2cusers', 'idn_roles', 'idn_useraccountmapping']
```

Comment: try this `tables.append(x[0])` if that does not work can you type `type(x)`

Comment: do you know y it worked ?

Comment: it takes the 0th element right?

Comment: the result from `cursor.fetchall()` is a List of Tuple when you iterate over it you get tuples which is in your case `x` which is a one element tuple. Now x[0] gives first element of the tuples

Comment: @VigneshKalai: Why don't post an answer? :)

Comment: Post as an answer, i will upvote

Comment: @KevinGuan thanks posted :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drop that loop and in instead do

```
tables = [t[0] for t in tablesWithDetails]
```

It will build a list containing the first element of each tuple in the result set.

Or even simpler (and cheaper), if you want a list then return an array which will be adapted to a list by Psycopg:

```
cursor.execute("""
    select array_agg(relname)
    from pg_class
    where relkind='r' and relname !~ '^(pg_|sql_)';"
""")
tables = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
```

Comment: Then how to run `x.replace("(", "")` and `x.replace(")", "")`?

Comment: @Kevin As I understand that is wrong. The OP was trying to "fix" or "cast" the tuples in the returned list supposing it could somehow be treated as a string.

Comment: Hmm...maybe. However tuples don't have `.replace()` method. Upvoted.

Comment: @KevinGuan that is what bothers be it should throw an error stating there is no `.replace method in a tuple`

Comment: @VigneshKalai: Do you mean about: Why doesn't OP's code raise an error about that `.replace`?

Comment: @Kevin Because he did not show the error and in instead just showed what he was trying?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: Hmm...but OP said: *This prints the table as follows,* `[('acam_datasegregationdetails',),...]`. So that is the output but OP doesn't want, and no error?

Comment: @Kevin The table output happens before the offending code: `print tablesWithDetails`

Comment: @KevinGuan it is just that I am sure that `x.replace("(", "")` will throw an error if `x` is an tuple since there is no replace method in tuple

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due this piece of code

```
tables.append(x)
```

When you execute `cursor.fetchall()` you will get a List of Tuples

and when you do `for x in tablesWithDetails:` you are iterating over the list by `one tuple at a time`

So when you do `tables.append(x)` you are appending a single element tuple to the list

To change that you could do this `tables.append(x[0])` it appends the first element of the tuple

Comment: By the way, what about `tables.extend(x)`?

Comment: @KevinGuan it would certainly work at this condition but what if there are many element in the tuple then `extend` would append all the element

Comment: Yep, just think that use `.extend` would be more clear  at this condition :P